# How can I determine why there is no water coming from my hot taps?

Tags: plumbing, boiler, water-pressure, freezing

I'm getting no water from any of the hot taps in my house. The cold water taps are working fine. The central heating is also working. I have a combi-boiler. It's been fairly cold today in London, so maybe a frozen pipe? Any ideas on how I can diagnose/fix the issue?

Comment: Please provide the make and model number of your boiler.

Comment: So are you getting cold water from your hot taps, or no water?

Comment: I have a ferroli domicondens he 26c combi boiler. And there is no water from the hot taps at all, hot or cold.

Comment: You're probably right about a frozen pipe - have you tried looking for any obviously frozen ones?